# Predual of disc algebra and $W(\mathbb{T})\neq A(\mathbb{D})$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, dual-spaces

I want prove that the [Wiener algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_algebra), $W(\mathbb{T})$, does not coincide with the [disc algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_algebra) $A(\mathbb{D})$. I know that there are some ways to do this. For example, one smart way is use Rudin-Shapiro sequence, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742940/about-wiener-algebra/2743232#2743232).

Note that $W(\mathbb{T})$ is an isometry to $\ell^1$, with pre-dual $c$ (or $c_0$, even [something else](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/45/4/789/348810?redirectedFrom=PDF)). However, I never hear story about *the pre-dual of disc algebra*.

> Question: Does $A(\mathbb{D})$ has pre-dual? What it is?

Comment: The first naive question would be: Has the unit ball of the disk algebra enough extreme points? Have you thought about this?

Comment: Yes. But it seems not directly to draw conclusion by applying Krein-Miliman theorem.

Comment: For information about extreme points, see this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3934564/extreme-points-of-disc-algebra. This is non-trivial, and discussed in Hoffman's book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, the Wiener algebra is isometric to $\ell_1$. In particular, it has the Schur property (weakly convergent sequences converge in the norm). However, this is very much not the case for the disc algebra as it, for example contains a sequence equivalent to the standard basis of $c_0$. It is a nice exercise to find explicitly a sequence in the disk algebra that converges weakly but not in the norm.

However, since $A(\mathbb D)$ is separable and contains a copy of $c_0$, by [Sobczyk's theorem](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.585.660&rep=rep1&type=pdf), this copy is complemented. No dual space contains a complemented copy of $c_0$ ([Theorem 2.4.15](https://books.google.cz/books?id=g2m3DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=c0%20is%20not%20complemented%20in%20a%20dual%20spae&source=bl&ots=_lawounmrg&sig=ACfU3U1SICKii0kTESGuk_HcgMHk41hPRA&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDlJWOrLH1AhXQ-yoKHQiYDlIQ6AF6BAgcEAM#v=onepage&q=c0%20is%20not%20complemented%20in%20a%20dual%20spae&f=false)). Hence $A(\mathbb D)$ is not isomorphic to a dual space.

For more details, see this [paper](https://www.esi.ac.at/preprints/esi710.pdf).

Comment: Interesting answer. But it seems to me that the main question is whether the disk algebra is a dual space. This is not covered by your answer, right?

Comment: @MaoWao, it is not. Please find my updated answer.

Comment: Even better! Thanks for the insights.

Comment: @Tomasz Kania, nice answer. I reconsiderd your exercise: If $(a_n)$ is a real sequence in $\mathbb{D}$ with limit $1$ and $f_n(z):=\left(\frac{z-a_n}{1-a_n z}\right)^2$, then $(f_n)$ is weakly convergent to $1$, but not in norm. Correct?

Comment: @Gerd Indeed you can use Hahn-Banach theorem, Riesz representation theorem, and DCT to get $f_n$ converge to $1$ weakly. But it seems $f_n\to 1$ in norm...

Comment: @Landau Since $f_n(a_n)=0$ it is impossible that $f_n \to 1$ in norm, On the other hand $(f_n)$ is norm bounded and pointwise convergent to $1$. Thus it should be weakly convergent to $1$.

Comment: @Gerd You are right and your example indeed work.